# Conditional Probability: $P(W|H)=\frac{2}{9},P(W|H^c)=\frac{5}{11},P(H)=\frac{1}{2},P(H|W)=$?

Tags: probability

I was marked wrong for this question on a probability and statistics quiz, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly:

- $P(W|H)=\frac{2}{9}$
- $P(W|H^c)=\frac{5}{11}$
- $P(H)=\frac{1}{2}$

What is $P(H|W)$?

My solution was as follows:

- $P(W)=P(W|H)\cdot P(H)+P(W|H^c)\cdot P(H^c)=\frac{2}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{11}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{5}{22}$
- $P(W|H)=\frac{P(W\cap H)}{P(H)}$
- $P(W\cap H)=P(W|H)\cdot P(H)=\frac{2}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{9}$

Hence $P(H|W)=\frac{P(H\cap W)}{P(W)}=\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{9}+\frac{5}{22}}$

What is my mistake? I've been trying to figure it out but I am stuck.

Comment: Clearly you've calculated $P(W)$ to be $\frac{2}{9}+\frac{5}{22}$, but then used $\frac{1}{9}+\frac{5}{22}$ instead.

Comment: That was just a typo, I meant to write 1/9 the first time too.

Answer (score 1):

I am convinced that you did not make any mistakes.

An equality that apart from $\Pr(H\mid W)$ only contains known probabilities: $$\Pr\left(W\mid H\right)\Pr\left(H\right)=\Pr\left(H\mid W\right)\left[\Pr\left(W\mid H\right)\Pr\left(H\right)+\Pr\left(W\mid H^{c}\right)\left(1-\Pr\left(H\right)\right)\right]$$

Substitution gives:

$\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2}=\Pr\left(H\mid W\right)\left[\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{11}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]$

Resulting in: $$\Pr\left(H\mid W\right)=\frac{\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{11}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{9}+\frac{5}{22}}$$